# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition;

Tags: php, laravel, artisan-migrate

**Migration File**

```php
$table->increments('id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
$table->foreign('band_id')->references('id')->on('bands');
$table->foreign('genre_id')->references('id')->on('genres');
$table->foreign('cate_id')->references('id')->on('cates');
$table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('types');
$table->integer('status');
$table->date('date');
$table->time('time');
$table->decimal('price');
$table->tinyIncrements('instrument');
$table->string('instrument_detail',255);
$table->timestamps();
```

After run php artisan migrate

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect
>   table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be
>   defined as a key (SQL: create table `bookings` (`id` int unsigned not
>   null auto_increment primary key, `status` int not null, `date`
>   date not null, `time` time not null, `price` decimal(8, 2) not null,
>   `instrument` tinyint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
>   `instrument_detail` varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp
>   null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character      set utf8mb4
>   collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

And this below

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect
>   table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be
>   defined as a key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$table->unsignedTinyInteger('instrument', true);
```

2nd parameter is bool for auto increment default to false

Answer (score 0):

The next sentence:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

just tells the db to make a link between the parent/foreign columns, but in order to do it the column must previously exist, so:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id'); // first this
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users'); // then this
```

You should do this for every foreign key.

Note:

Laravel doens't need you to define this links because it doens't make use of this, is just for database consistency sake.

Comment: thank HCK :( but still  didn’t  work can't migration they say SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075  in the sameway

Comment: @chojon check Ahmed's solution.

Comment: so i try it but didn't work all i wanna know why they still can't run migrate then i will find some same case this problem thank pow